One server unreachable from VPN, but accessible from LAN
I have several servers behind a router that requires VPN to connect to them, which has been working for months. This week, one of them started rejecting SSH connections from the VPN, but other computers in the LAN can connect to it.
Diagnostics

When I try to SSH into it, I can see the packets in a tcpdump of the router, but not at the server.
Using the pfSense interface, the router can ping it from the LAN interface and OpenVPN clients, but not the OpenVPN server interface. Other machines that work normally respond to pings from the OpenVPN server.
I have added a specific NAT allow rule from OpenVPN to the IP and port of the computer in question.

Other info
The router is using pfSense CE and OpenVPN. The server is running Ubuntu 24.04.
The machine that is giving us trouble is the only one using a non-standard SSH port, but that was like that before. I added the following lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 22
Port 51345  # Old port

followed by systemctl daemon-reload and systemctl restart ssh, but port 22 is still closed, even for machines on LAN, and as reported by nmap.
sshd -T does not report any errors.
ufw is disabled on the problematic host.
No one has admitted to changing anything in the configuration before it broke.
There is no further segmentation at LAN.
